# nanopi neo air QtEmbedded-4.8.6-arm related

Tags: air, qt4, pi

If you click the UI button with a USB mouse in the QT program, it works at once.
When you click a UI button by touch, the mouse point moves and you have to click again to activate the button.

How can I make the UI button work with a single touch?(on_Btn_main_clicked  event)
(Using setqt4env_matrix)

thank you